# when textbox are null it will not insert data

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

What I want to happen is if the text in `txtEmail1` or `txtEmail2` is null or just one textbox it will not save data.... and what happens in my code is despite the conditions that I put, still saves data in the database with a null value in the email column

```
            cmd = connection.CreateCommand();

            if ((txtEmail1.Text == null) & (txtEmail2.Text == null))
            {

            }
            else if ((txtEmail1.Text != null) & (txtEmail2.Text != null)) 
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO email(Id,email)VALUES( @Id,@email)";
                string[] email = new string[2];
                email[0] = txtEmail1.Text;
                email[1] = txtEmail2.Text;
                for (int i = 0; i < 2; i += 1)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", int.Parse(txtId.Text));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email[i]);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }

            else if (txtEmail1.Text != null)
            {
                if (txtEmail2.Text == null)
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO email(Id,email)VALUES( @Id,@email)";

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", int.Parse(txtId.Text));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtEmail1.Text);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Try using string.IsNullOrEmpty method instead of comparing to null

Comment: Yep, `TextBox.Text` isn't null, it's an empty string.  you want `String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtEmail1.Text);` etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TextBox.Text` would never be `null` you need to check it against empty string. You can use

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text)
```

Or if you want to consider white space as null then you can use

```
string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox.Text);
```

[`string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is provided with .Net framework 4.0 and higher.

So your check could be:

```
if ((string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtEmail1.Text)) && 
    (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtEmail2.Text))))
```

Also use double `&&` which would cause short circuiting

Comment: how about detecting the textbox if not null?

Comment: @davz_11, `TextBox` can be `null` and you can compare it like `if(textBox != null)` but that should only bother you if you are declaring `TextBox` in your code behind and not generating it through designers. If you create a `TextBox` through designer it's `Text` property could contain an empty string but it can never be null.

Comment: what is designers by the way... sorry i'm just a beginner in c#

Comment: See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5yd62ts(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Use [`String.IsNullOrEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtEmail1.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtEmail2.Text))
{
   // don't save the data
}
else
{
  ..
}
```

Also you can use `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` to check for WhiteSpace as mentiond in the other answer.Or if you want to combine functionalities of these two method you can create a simple extension method:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
     public static bool IsEmptyOrWhiteSpace(this string source)
     {
          return source.Trim(' ').Length == 0 || source.Length == 0;
     }
}
```

Usage:

```
if(txtEmail1.Text.IsEmptyOrWhiteSpace() 
   || txtEmail2.Text.IsEmptyOrWhiteSpace())
```